# Meteor + React - window.onpopstate not working

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to intercept clicks on the `back` button in the browser.
In a React component, I am doing this:

```
componentWillMount() { /* also tried componentDidMount() */
    window.onpopstate = (e)=>{
        console.log(e)
};
```

But nothing happens.
What is the right way to intercept the back button (or popstate) event?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever get it figured out?

Comment: Bumped into the same problem, found that calling history.pushState({}, ''); make an event fired. But this solution not working in safari(

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't working for me if I reassigned `window.onpopstate` inside my `componentWillUnmount` since the component unmounted before the event occurred.